# How To Add Dependent Dropdown In React-Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs I am trying to learn React-js. I want to build dependent dropdown Menu. Where if I select Genre fiction it should display books in fiction genre. All this is hardcoded for now I haven't linked it to the database/backend.

I searched few things and came up with this but its not working properly.

```
class Dropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Genres: [],
      Books: [],
      selectedGenre: "--Choose Genre--",
      selectedBook: "--Choose Book--",
    };

    this.ChangeGenre = this.ChangeGenre.bind(this);
    this.ChangeBook = this.ChangeBook.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      Genres: [
        { name: "Fiction", Books: ["GOT", "LOTR", "Harry Potter"] },
        { name: "Murder", Books: ["Dragon", "Tattoo", "Girl"] },
        { name: "Thriller", Books: ["Angel", "Lost Symbol", "Davinci"] },
      ],
    });
  }

  ChangeGenre(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedGenre: event.target.value,
    });
    this.setState({
      Books: this.state.Genres.find((b) => b.name === event.target.value).Books,
    });
  }

  ChangeBook(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedBook: e.target.value });
    const stats = this.state.Genres.find(
      (g) => g.name === this.state.selectedGenre
    ).Books;
    this.setState({
      Books: stats.find((stat) => stat === e.target.value).Books,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>

        <div>
          <label>Genre</label>
          <select
            placeholder="Genre"
            value={this.state.selectedGenre}
            onChange={this.ChangeGenre}
          >
            <option>--Choose Genre--</option>
            {this.state.Genres.map((e, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Books</label>
          <select
            placeholder="Books"
            value={this.state.selectedBook}
            onChange={this.ChangeBook}
          >
            <option>--Choose Book--</option>
            {this.state.Books.map((e, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{e.name}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Books Dropdown doesn't show any books and on clicking any option throws an error cannot read 'Books' of Undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Dropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Genres: [],
      Books: [],
      selectedGenre: '--Choose Genre--',
      selectedBook: '--Choose Book--'
    };

    this.ChangeGenre = this.ChangeGenre.bind(this);
    this.ChangeBook = this.ChangeBook.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      Genres: [
        { name: "Fiction", Books: ["GOT", "LOTR", "Harry Potter"] },
        { name: "Murder", Books: ["Dragon", "Tattoo", "Girl"] },
        { name: "Thriller", Books: ["Angel", "Lost Symbol", "Davinci"] }
      ]
    });
  }

  ChangeGenre(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const Books = this.state.Genres.find(
      (genre) => genre.name === e.target.value
    ).Books;
    this.setState({ selectedGenre: e.target.value, Books });
  }

  ChangeBook(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ selectedBook: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <h2>Cascading or Dependent Dropdown using React</h2>

        <div>
          <label>Genre</label>
          <select
            placeholder="Genre"
            value={this.state.selectedGenre}
            onChange={this.ChangeGenre}
          >
            <option>--Choose Genre--</option>
            {this.state.Genres.map((genre, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{genre.name}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Books</label>
          <select
            placeholder="Books"
            value={this.state.selectedBook}
            onChange={this.ChangeBook}
            disabled={this.state.selectedGenre === '--Choose Genre--'}
          >
            <option>--Choose Book--</option>
            {this.state.Books.map((book, key) => {
              return <option key={key}>{book}</option>;
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not to late, you can also try [React Conditional Selection](https://react-conditional-select.vercel.app) approach.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.